# How to implement SSO for Tuleap using Shibboleth

Tags: single-sign-on, integration, shibboleth, tuleap

My company is using shibboleth to perform Single sign on. 
The applications we use to sign in are wordpress and Owncloud. Now, We are planning to include Tuleap Open ALM (Application Lifecycle Management) to use shibboleth to do single sign on.

So is there a plug-in to do it, A way it can be done or is it possible or impossible, Could you provide your views and thoughts to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no explicit plugin for Tuleap to use shibboleth. However, I think shibboleth [can be used with openId](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdP+OpenID) and that Tuleap can also be configured to use openId. The other Tuleap authentication methods are native and ldap.